# Getting error while trying to connect to oracle server using .net window application

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g, database-connection, connection-string

I have developed a window application using VS2008 and while I am trying to connect to database getting error

> "Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12154".
>   Path in environment file : D:\app\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin
>   Path in ORACLE_HOME:D:\app\product\11.2.0\client_1

Could anyone please help as i am not able to resolve it.

Comment: Can you post the connection code? Error string is *ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified*.

Comment: @LaurIvan here is the connection string :"Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=3SS_TEST;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test123;Password=test"

Comment: Do you have a 64bit install? According [to this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1022162) `MSDAORA` only has 32bit.

Comment: @LaurIvan do you mean i need 32 bit oracle client to use MSDAORA ??

Comment: According to the above link, yes.

Comment: @LaurIvan  i have used 32 bit oracle client, please help to fix this out as it is causing lots of problem to my project.

Comment: @LaurIvan could you please help .